# Office 365 Outlook Add-In Custom Pane

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, office-addins

I'm looking into creating an Outlook addin for Office365 store which directly integrates into the Outlook compose pane. I wish to follow the UI structure shown [in this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt484316.aspx), the custom pane, however there are no details on how to do it, any any App for Office I make seems to create the generic task pane.

How would I go about having my application create UI elements in Outlook's compose pane?

Answer (score 1):

to deliver the best developer experience, you want to build an add-in command in compose window. Check out these two blog posts on this feature, along with a sample posted at the end of the second one. That sample shows you how to create a button in the ribbon of a message compose window.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/08/31/introducing-add-in-commands.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/09/01/building-add-ins-with-commands.aspx

Very soon, the Office store will require that add-ins which integrate into compose window use commands, so you should follow these posts.

While we do have tooling in Visual Studio, it's currently only showing how to build an add-in without a command. We're currently working on upgrading the tooling to support commands as well, so for the time being please use the samples referenced in the blog posts.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response. I understand why I was having such an issue with it in Visual Studio then. I sort of understand how the new 1.1 Manifest works, however it seems the Custom Pane is for read forms only? My main goal is to have a ComboBox below the To/CC/BCC textboxes to select from an item list. What would be the best approach to this? Thanks.

Comment: you can add a dropdown (menu) command to the ribbon and have the user select from there. Check out this sample, which shows you how to create each type of supported command.

https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo

Comment: I wish to take advantage of the custom pane in the future to provide more streamlined, integrated office apps. Do you perhaps have an example which uses the CustomPane ExtensionPoint?

Comment: I wish to take advantage of the CustomPane at some point in the future to provide integrated Outlook addins in the future for Office365. Do you perhaps have an example in which the CustomPane ExtensionPoint is used to use as a reference?